trouble with calling pwsh through windows terminal command line
This is something I have been struggling with for a few days and each time I think I have adjourned it, it falls apart.
I want to launch a new Windows Terminal window but with two caveats:

The new terminal must be a windows terminal profile
At the same time, pass a command line argument to the WT profile's shell, which is pwsh, so pwsh's -command parameter

A few days ago, I figured out how to send command line arguments to the profiles shell, Pass a command line argument to the new terminal window that is about to be launched? #17521.
This successfully opens a new terminal window with my_profile profile. The host prints my message:
wt -p my_profile pwsh -noExit -command "'my message'"

All was good and well until it broke on me today. The following does open a new terminal window but the window prints an error:
wt -p my_profile pwsh -noExit -command "'my message' ; 'my second message'"

The error is printed by windows terminal (not pwsh):
[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `" 'my second message'"']

If I eliminate WT from the equation, pwsh correctly receives input to its -command parameter:
pwsh -noExit -command "'my message' ; 'my second message'"


#my message
#my second message

Is pwsh really not at fault here?
Is there some sort of pwsh mechanism that can help me to navigate around this issue?
I would appreciate any solutions in either pwsh or wt
Windows Terminal 1.19 preview
pwsh 7.4
win 11

Why do you need to pass a command line argument? (Wondering if this is really an XY problem...)

@Bill_Stewart A ton of reasons. For example, I want to launch WT profiles, then set the profile's shell to a desired state. I want to do this on the go, at the command line, rather than hard code it in the profile definition or in some .ps1/.bat/.py file.

Is the question really "How do I escape the ; character in the command line field a Windows Terminal profile?"

@Bill_Stewart as of mclaytons's asnswer, that was the crux of the issue and what the quesion should have been.

Windows Terminal uses ; to separate "actions" in the wt command line:

Command line syntax
The wt command line accepts two types of values: options and commands.

Options are a list of flags and other parameters that can control the behavior of the wt command line as a whole.

Commands provide the action, or list of actions separated by semicolons, that should be implemented. If no command is specified, then the command is assumed to be new-tab by default.



So, if you look back at your wt command line:
wt -p my_profile pwsh -noExit -command "'my message' ; 'my second message'"

Windows Terminal is trying to run the equivalent of:
wt -p my_profile ; new-tab pwsh -noExit -command "'my message' ; new-tab 'my second message'"

first  "action":           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
second "action":                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

and you end up with a new Windows Terminal with two tabs - one for each new-tab "action":

pwsh -noExit -command "'my message' - the first tab has the output my message - note that even though the " quotes in the -command argument aren't closed properly, powershell still executes it fine (you can try it from a command prompt, but not an interactive powershell session)

 'my second message'" - the second tab has the error message [error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `" 'my second message'"'] because  'my second message'" isn't a valid command. (Note the extra leading " in the error - I'm presuming Windows Terminal has added this because the second command starts with a space character, but I'm not sure tbh).


Workaround
I couldn't find it documented, but I tried escaping ; as \; which seems to work - wt will then treat the \; as a literal ; in the "action" command:
wt -p my_profile pwsh -noExit -command "'my message' \; 'my second message'"

single action:   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

and you end up with a single tab with the output:
my message
my second message


Note - all of the above was tested in a Windows Command Prompt - it's possible different escaping rules will apply depending on where you're calling wt from...

man, how did I miss that fine detail. Thank you for looking into and also for discovering WT possibly uses \ as an escape character. I can confirm that your solution works in Powershell 7 too.
